# Android Listview : How to change font-style and font color in xml ?? and display divider in xml

Tags: android

Im new in android programming.. I just wanna ask how to change a font-style and font-color in xml ???.. and how can i display the divider in xml? Thank you

Comment: These questions have been asked a lot of times. Use search first.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:textcolor for color and android:typeface for the font
for using your custom font you can use the following from java

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview03);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Molot.otf");
text.setTypeface(tf);
```

where you put your custom font file in the assets folder.

Comment: This is for a textview, to use this in a listview I would suggest that you create a custom inflatable row and bind that to your listview using adapters, and in your custom row you can set this code for your textview. You can download the font file from here(http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Droid-Sans).